# How can I create a SockJS client in a Phonegap/Cordova Android app?

Tags: cordova, websocket, sockjs

I have been trying to get a Cordova (3.3) app working with SockJS. I really want "real" websockets, that is, fallback to XHR (etc) should be as rare as possible. I've been looking through various plugins and whatnot, but I have yet to find a combination that works. So far, I can only get Android 4.4x devices, which have native websockets, to work.

Are there any "known good" plugins for this purpose?

If so, how do I wire them into the Cordova app such that SockJS-client uses them to initialize rather than trying and failing to create websockets, followed by various polling methods?